# UI thread is block, stopwatch implement

Tags: android, multithreading

I to try to make stop watch in my android app.

When I use this code my UI thread is blocked(app is forzen)

I cant figure out why because my Log calls for checking thread sleep are fine.

Here is my code, thanks for helping.

```
public void startStopWatch()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(stopThread == false)  
            {   

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.i("sleep", "sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            workoutTime++;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    workoutTimeText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.starting_wrokout_time) + getWorkoutTime());
                }
            });

            }
            }
        }).run();

    }
```

**EDIT**

I solved it this way:

```
public void stopWatchTest()
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                workoutTime++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        workoutTimeText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.starting_wrokout_time) + getWorkoutTime());

                        stopWatchTest();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: use a CountDownTimer ?

Comment: I want to count up not down.

Comment: then use postDelayed on a handler rather than creating a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the .start() method.

When you directly call the .run() method, you run it on the calling thread rather than in the new thread you are creating.

That said, creating a thread and having it sleep is probably not the best means of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people will do something like :

```
public void startStopWatch() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!stopThread) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
            workoutTime++;
            workoutTimeText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.starting_wrokout_time) + getWorkoutTime());
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

There may be some deviation due to the posting to the handler, so there are methods to make sure you post at the right time.